# WebRTC - addStream() to host connection

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to play audio from a file to a remote webrtc peer. I can get the peers connected and mic audio flows back and forth between them, no problem. However when I add an audio stream to the remote peer then the audio from the stream doesn't play on the remote peer's system.

This is on Linux using Chrome 56 for the local system and Firefox 51 for the remote peer.

The file loads into the buffer fine, I tested this by attaching a MediaRecorder and monitoring its ondataavailable() event, data is definitely going into buffer and on to the source_dest below.

Here's the basic flow below. What am I doing wrong?

**pc1** is the localhost system's AudioContext already set up. The **mic_stream** below is the stream from pc1 calling getUserMedia(), which  gets the local mic.

```
// create a new stream source from the pc1 stream
mic_patch = pc1.context.createMediaStreamSource( mic_stream );

// create a new destination from the mic stream
source_dest = pc1.context.createMediaStreamDestination();

// create a new filter, we need this so that source_dest
// creates a stream that we can add to pc2.
biquadfilter = pc1.context.createBiquadFilter();
biquadfilter.type = 'highpass';
biquadfilter.frequency.value = 1500;

// connect the mic_patch to the filter
mic_patch.connect( biquadfilter );

// connect the filter to the new source dest
biquadfilter.connect( source_dest );
```

After **pc2** connects successfully to pc1, mic audio works between pc1 and pc2, all is good. Then I add the source_dest stream to pc2 (RTCPeerConnection), and when I examine pc2 via pc2.getLocalStreams() I see that the source_dest stream is connected.

```
pc2.addStream( source_dest.stream );
```

Then I load a file from disk into a buffer.

At this point **file** in the code below is a File object loaded by using a HTML <input type="file"> field. When the file is selected that triggers the code below.

I convert that to an AudioBuffer using FileReader and decode it to a buffer using createBufferSource() which is connected to the source_dest so buffer_source feeds its output into source_dest, then I start playing immediately via buffer_source.start(0)

```
reader = new FileReader(); 

buffer_source = source_dest.context.createBufferSource();

buffer_source.connect( source_dest );

reader.onload = function(e) {
    var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
    Webcaster.node.context.decodeAudioData( arrayBuffer, function(buffer) {

        buffer_source.buffer = buffer;

        buffer_source.start(0);

        /** For testing to ensure the buffer data makes it into source_dest
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder( source_dest.stream );
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(evt) {
            // push each chunk (blobs) in an array
            chunks.push(evt.data);
            // dump out the chunks array to ensure it receives buffer data successfully
            console.log( 'CHUNKS', chunks );
        };
        mediaRecorder.start();
        //stop recording after 10 seconds, no need to record longer,
        //this is only to test the source_dest connect and data flow
        //when recorders stop ondataavailable() will be triggered
        setTimeout( function() { mediaRecorder.stop() }, 10000 )
        **/
    })
}

reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );
```

So all of that works, except that the audio data put into source_dest does not get played on the remote pc2. I've spent many hours trying to sort out why, so far no luck.

Anybody have clues why?

Comment: I discovered that this is a browser compatibility issue. Apparently Chrome (as of v56) uses what is called "Plan B" for WebRTC SDP connection negotiation while FireFox (as of v51) uses what is called "UnifiedPlan" and they are incompatible when it comes to add/removing streams and track due to the connection negotiation that must take place.

So, the above scenario works for FF to FF, and Chrome to Chrome. But at this time no cross-browser compat.

Comment: There is a lib from the makers of Jitsi called "sdp-interop" that can help to a limited extent. When using that, as long as Chrome is the initiator of the call then Firefox can connected when Chrome as additional tracks added to its stream. 

References: 

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465349

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/firefox-multistream-and-renegotiation-for-jitsi-videobridge/